# Testing using a real android device inside a virtual box

Tags: android, testing, virtualbox

My Android project development environment is set up inside a virtual box machine which is a windows vista 32 bit. This windows virtual box lies on mac os. I'm trying to use my android phone to test the code changes in virtual box. Though the windows(virtual box) sees the phone, it recognizes the phone as a USB device. Hence my device doesn't appear under "Other devices" in the "DEvice manager".

I downloaded the device driver for samsung usb composite device but the installation fails with "Error Code 10". I tried with "Google USB driver" but the system doesn't accept the same, saying "Your system has already installed the best device driver - Samsung Composite Device Driver".

Query:

Is it possible to connect an android device through host machine (mac os) and use it for testing in virtual box (windows vista 32 bit)?

If so, can you please shed some light on what I'm missing to configure?

Comment: why dont you use genymotion it works on mac and runs android OS on virtualbox too.http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Check if your virtual Box Actually detecting USB .. If No there is an option of bridge USB with virtualBox. add your device and it'll function :)

Comment: The virtual box is detecting my usb. Only driver installation fails. I wont be able to do anything in mac since that is a different person's computer.